# About XML Schema

Tags: xml

Consider following two examples:

**Example 1:**

```
<xs:import namespace="http://example.com/ns" schemaLocation="test.xsd"/>
```

**Example2:**

```
<sample:Data Test="true" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/test.xsd">
```

How these two examples are different? What is purpose of `namespace` ? Is it a required field, as I can not see in second example. (What kind of document should be available in the URL defined by the namespace? eg. some xml file or xsd file etc?)

Also, in first example there is `schemaLocation` while in second there is `xsi:schemaLocation`, what is diffence between these two? Also, what does the `Test=true` in second example mean?
Thanks.

Comment: The two exampes have nothing whatsoever in common.  Why do tyou think they do the same thing?

Comment: He/she's probably only just starting to learn XML and is a bit bewildered. We're here to help, right? If someone asks a question that seems nonsensical, make them see sense. Mani, before learning anything about XML Schema or namespaces, first learn the basics of XML. The `Test="true"` there is simply an attribute in that document. It only means whatever the software processing that document makes of it.

Comment: @G_H, Thanks for your kind comment. yes, i just started learning XML, and i was looking at some xml examples, and couldnt find explanation for those, so i asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xs:import element is used in an XML **schema** to import definitions from another schema with a different target namespace. This is why you must specify that namespace. The xsi:schemaLocation attribute is used in an XML **document** to indicate which schema defines the syntax for the XML document.

xsi:schemaLocation is not necessarily used by whatever processes the XML document.